# Flutter freezed package - Error: Type '$UserProfileCopyWith' not found in Xcode build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, freezed, flutter-freezed

### Issue

Please help me . The issue I'm struggling with occurs as I add a Freezed class `UserProfile` included in a local package `user_profile_repository`

to the Freezed class `HomeUserProfileState` representing loading state of fetching user data for the home screen

and being part of `HomeState`.

As running **flutter run** xcode build fails:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPad mini (6th generation) in debug mode...
main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                            9.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): lib/home/cubit/home_cubit.freezed.dart:1147:3: Error: Type '$UserProfileCopyWith' not found.
home_cubit.freezed.dart:1147
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPad mini (6th generation).
Exited
```

The packages versions I'm using are resolved by **flutter pub get** to freezed 2.4.5, freezed_annotation 2.4.1 and build_runner 2.4.6.

Below I included hopefully all information necessary for your support. Please tell me if you're missing something.

### Local package 'user_profile_repository'

```dart
part 'user_profile.freezed.dart';

@freezed
class UserProfile with _$UserProfile {
  factory UserProfile({
    required String id,
    required String username,
    required String email,
    required String firstName,
  }) = _UserProfile;

  factory UserProfile.fromUserAttributes(
    List<AuthUserAttribute> userAttributes,
  ) =>
      UserProfileConverter().convert(userAttributes);
}
```

*packages/user_profile_repository/lib/src/models/user_profile.dart*

`UserProfile` is exported in the package.

```dart
export 'src/models/user_profile.dart';
export 'src/user_profile_repository.dart';
```

*packages/user_profile_repository/lib/user_profile_repository.dart*

### HomeUserProfileState and HomeState classes

Here is how `UserProfile` is included into `HomeUserProfileState.loaded`:

```dart
part of 'home_cubit.dart';

@freezed
class HomeState with _$HomeState {
  const factory HomeState({
    @Default(HomeMoodsState.initial()) HomeMoodsState moodsState,
    @Default(HomeUserProfileState.initial())
    HomeUserProfileState userProfileState,
  }) = _HomeState;
}

@freezed
class HomeUserProfileState with _$HomeUserProfileState {
  const factory HomeUserProfileState.initial() = HomeUserProfileInitialState;
  const factory HomeUserProfileState.loading() = HomeUserProfileLoadingState;
  const factory HomeUserProfileState.loaded({
    required user_profile_repository.UserProfile userProfile,
  }) = HomeUserProfileSuccessState;
  const factory HomeUserProfileState.error() = HomeUserProfileErrorState;
}

// ...
```

*lib/home/cubit/home_state.dart*

As I delete the parameter `userProfile` in `HomeUserProfileState.loaded` and run build_runner again xcode build runs without issues.

### HomeCubit

The class `HomeCubit` emits the state using `HomeState`.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:mood_repository/mood_repository.dart';
import 'package:user_profile_repository/user_profile_repository.dart'
    as user_profile_repository;

part 'home_cubit.freezed.dart';
part 'home_state.dart';

class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  HomeCubit({
    required MoodRepository moodRepository,
    required DataStoreCategory dataStore,
    required user_profile_repository.UserProfileRepository
        userProfileRepository,
  })  : _moodRepository = moodRepository,
        _userProfileRepository = userProfileRepository,
        _dataStore = dataStore,
        super(const HomeState());

  final MoodRepository _moodRepository;

  final user_profile_repository.UserProfileRepository _userProfileRepository;

  final DataStoreCategory _dataStore;

  late final StreamSubscription<SubscriptionEvent<MoodEntry>>? moodEntryStream;

  Future<void> init() async {
    await loadUserProfile();
    await loadMoods();
    listenMoodEntryChanges();
  }

  // ...
  
  Future<void> loadUserProfile() async {
    try {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          userProfileState: const HomeUserProfileState.loading(),
        ),
      );

      final userProfile = await _userProfileRepository.fetchUserProfile();

      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          userProfileState: HomeUserProfileState.loaded(
            userProfile: userProfile,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          userProfileState: const HomeUserProfileState.error(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

As I delete the parameter `userProfile` in `HomeUserProfileState.loaded` and run build_runner again xcode build runs without issues.